# How to fix the tm package loading large amounts of documents in strange order?

Tags: r, tm

I'm using `tm` in R, and dealing with 10k documents.  I wanted to inspect some by indices, but they weren't matching the files.  Why does tm load large amounts of documents in a weird order, and how can it be fixed/subverted?  Here is an example:

```
library(tm)

docs <- c()
for (i in 1:10000) {
  docs <- c(docs, paste('test', i))
}

cor <- VCorpus(VectorSource(docs))

filepath = '/home/nate/Dropbox/MSDS/MSDS682_ncg_F8W2_17/test_cor'
writeCorpus(cor, path = filepath)

cor2 <- VCorpus(DirSource(filepath))

as.character(cor2[[1]])
as.character(cor2[[2]])
as.character(cor2[[3]])
as.character(cor2[[4]])
```

This prints out:

```
test 10000
test 1000
test 1001
test 1002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result comes about due to the filenames created by `writeCorpus`. In your *path* you will find files named `1.txt, 10.txt, 100.txt, 1000.txt, 1001.txt ... n.txt`

When you read them back in with `DirSource` they are coming in using that text sort instead of your expected numeric.

To keep your sort order as intended you can add the `filenames` argument to `writeCorpus`, for example:

```
writeCorpus(
  cor,
  path = filepath,
  filenames = paste0(sprintf("%05d", 1:length(cor)), ".txt")
)
```

Which will make your file output, `00001.txt, 00002.txt, 00003.txt ... n.txt`, and your import back from disk will be read in the correct order.